# Sveltekit optional params links

Tags: sveltekit

I have a routing structure like this:

`/[lang]]/products/[[category]]`
and
`/[[lang]]/product/[id]`

I have a language toggle in my layout. How do I build links to update / add in the `[[lang]]` optional parameter without changing other parts of the URL?

I've put this all into a component below, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { page } from "$app/stores";
  export let routeKey = 'lang';
  export let value = 'en';

  $: console.log("paa", $page);

  const optionalRegex = /\[\[.*\]\]/;
  const routeGroupRegex = /\(.*\)/;
  $: validKey = $page.route.id?.includes(`[[${routeKey}]]`);
  let link = "";

  $: {
    link = $page.route.id!.replace(`[[${routeKey}]]`, value);
    for (let key in $page.params) {
      link = link
        .replace(`[[${key}]]`, $page.params[key] || "") // If optional route exists, replace it with the existing value
        .replace(`[${key}]`, $page.params[key]); // Required routes will always exist
    }
    link = link.replace(optionalRegex, "").replace(routeGroupRegex, "");
  }
</script>

{#if !validKey}
  <p>Invalid key provided</p>
{:else}
  <slot {link} />
{/if}
```

I've tried doing a bunch of checks to determine what route the user is on and then rebuilding the url using $page.route.id as a starting point, but it gets cumbersome when there are other optional route params which may or may not exist.